# Data no change when swipe to refresh with Fragment

Tags: java, android

I have problem with swipe to refresh, I have add SwipeRefreshLayout to layout activity_main.xml after that I set action for setOnRefreshListener.

layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
        <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/container_body_vn"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swipeToRefresh"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout_vn"/>

        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And in main_activity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.soccer_activity_main_vn);
mSwipeRefreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.swipeToRefresh);

 mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            Fragment fragment = null;

            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                int current_tab = viewPager.getCurrentItem();

                switch (current_tab) {
                    case 0:
                        fragment = new TV_Fragment();
                        break;

                    default:
                        break;
                }

                if (fragment != null) {
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body_vn, fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

I tried to run App data in App no change after pull to refresh, and the icon refresh loading forever. I don't know why, anyone know please give me some comment.

Sorry for my english.

Thanks

Comment: For the refreshing icon to go away you need to execute : mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false)

Comment: The fragment will always be null so how you want to pass the if and make the commit?

Comment: @AhmedAli I know the fragment when I choosed tab in  viewPagerint current_tab = viewPager.getCurrentItem();

Answer (score 0):

-if you want hide refresh icon after load and swipe , should add mSipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

-if you want disable refreshing after one load and swipe , should add
mSipreRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false);

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        Fragment fragment = null;

        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            int current_tab = viewPager.getCurrentItem();

            switch (current_tab) {
                case 0:
                    fragment = new TV_Fragment();
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

            if (fragment != null) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body_vn, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();


            }

            mSipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false); //mSipreRefreshLayout.setEnabled(false); for disabled swipe

        }
    });
```